# Excel - vba, assign formula value to variable

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba

I'm using vba code to get total values from a column depending on some criteria.
[Attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NV7sD.jpg) is the image I'm using to explain what I'm trying to achieve.

I want to do this as I will sum all the values and put in a different cell and as I'm using dynamic variables in my formula I don't want to write multiple times the same code.

Something like: total = total + valueOnCell[i]

Not so cool code:

```
Function siteTraffic(currentMonth As Integer, currentYear As Integer) As Integer

Dim total As Integer
Dim start As Integer
Dim step As Integer

If currentMonth = 7 Then

   Sheets("Calculations").Range("d7").Formula = "=SUM(SUMIFS(Data[Sessions],Data[Month of the year],""=" & currentMonth & """,Data[Year],""=" & currentYear & """,Data[Segment],{""=Geo - International"",""=Geo - US & LATAM""}))"


    ElseIf currentMonth = 8 Then

    Sheets("Calculations").Range("d7").Formula = "=SUM(SUMIFS(Data[Sessions],Data[Month of the year],""=" & currentMonth & """,Data[Year],""=" & currentYear & """,Data[Segment],{""=Geo - International"",""=Geo - US & LATAM""}))" _
    & "+SUM(SUMIFS(Data[Sessions],Data[Month of the year],""= 7 "",Data[Year],""=" & currentYear & """,Data[Segment],{""=Geo - International"",""=Geo - US & LATAM""}))"

     ElseIf currentMonth = 9 Then


    Sheets("Calculations").Range("d7").Formula = "=SUM(SUMIFS(Data[Sessions],Data[Month of the year],""=" & currentMonth & """,Data[Year],""=" & currentYear & """,Data[Segment],{""=Geo - International"",""=Geo - US & LATAM""}))" _
    & "+SUM(SUMIFS(Data[Sessions],Data[Month of the year],""= 7 "",Data[Year],""=" & currentYear & """,Data[Segment],{""=Geo - International"",""=Geo - US & LATAM""}))" _
    & "+SUM(SUMIFS(Data[Sessions],Data[Month of the year],""= 8 "",Data[Year],""=" & currentYear & """,Data[Segment],{""=Geo - International"",""=Geo - US & LATAM""}))"

       End If
   End Select
End Function
```

---

I 'm trying to change my code so it will be dynamically wrtitten but I get an overflow error

```
Function siteTraffic(currentMonth As Integer, currentYear As Integer) As Integer
'currentMonth will be 01-12
'currentYear will be >=2016
Dim step As Integer 
Dim start As Integer

For start = 1 To currentMonth

    Sheets("Calculations").Range("d7").Formula = "=SUM(SUMIFS(Data[Sessions],Data[Month of the year],""=" & start & """,Data[Year],""=" & currentYear & """,Data[Segment],{""=Geo - International"",""=Geo - US & LATAM""}))"

    step = Sheets("Calculations").Range("d7").Value + step

    Next start

    End If
```

My question is how do I store the value calculated by each cell in a variable so I only have to sum each value through an iteration instead of copy/paste the same code over and over?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That might be because you are using integer as your var type. You should reserve more memory with a `long`, `double` or `variant`. If the variant Type has decimals then cast it like this `variant = CDec(variant)`.

```
Function siteTraffic(currentMonth As Integer, currentYear As Integer) As Integer
'currentMonth will be 01-12
'currentYear will be >=2016
Dim step As Double <- you need something bigger 
Dim start As Integer

For start = 1 To currentMonth

    Sheets("Calculations").Range("d7").Formula = "=SUM(SUMIFS(Data[Sessions],Data[Month of the year],""=" & start & """,Data[Year],""=" & currentYear & """,Data[Segment],{""=Geo - International"",""=Geo - US & LATAM""}))"

    step = Sheets("Calculations").Range("d7").Value + step

Next start

End If
```

Comment: That worked at first attempt, thank you dmb.